# Python MQTT - Understanding the Scenario

Tags: python, mqtt, fastapi

I have the following requirements to implement.

The application should offer simple REST API interface taking inputs for add operation and returning calculation result. The application should offer Mqtt interface

1. Subscribe for topic e.g. calculator/add and accept payload e.g. {“number1”:10, “number2”:20}
2. Publish result calculator/add/result e.g. { “final_result”:30}

Above points are a bit ambiguous. To my understanding of the above points;

So in simply, I should write an `/add` post endpoint with query parameters and get those two numbers and publish them to the `add` endpoint. And in the same endpoint, I should write my subscription logic to the same `add` topic and get the two numbers and add them and then again publish it to the `result` topic and again subscribe to the `result` topic and return the result value as a json output?

I came up with the following python snippet:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging
import os

# Configuring the logging level
logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"), format='%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M:%S',)

# Creating an instance of FastAPI with a title and a description
app = FastAPI(title="My Sweet Calculator", description="A simple service that taking inputs for add operation and returning calculation resul")

# Defining the broker, port, topic and client id to use for the MQTT connection
BROKER = 'mqtt.eclipseprojects.io'
PORT = 1883
PUBLISHER_TOPIC = "calculator/add/RESULT"
SUBSCRIBER_TOPIC = "calculator/add/RESULT"
CLIENT_ID = 'CALCULATER_RESULTS'

# Defining a callback function that gets triggered when the MQTT client connects to the broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        logging.info("Connected to MQTT Broker!")        
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

# Creating an instance of the MQTT client with the defined client id and connecting it to the broker using the defined port
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(CLIENT_ID)
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.connect(BROKER, PORT)

# endpoint '/add' that accepts two query params 'a' and 'b' and publishing the result to the topic 'calculator'
@app.get("/add")
async def add(a: int = Query(..., gt=0), b: int = Query(..., gt=0)):

    result = a + b

    mqtt_client.publish(PUBLISHER_TOPIC, json.dumps({"a": a, "b": b}))
    logging.info("PUBLISHED values of \'a\' and \'b\'" + " to Topic " + PUBLISHER_TOPIC)

    return {"result": result}

# Defining a callback function that gets triggered when a message is received on the topic 'calculator'. 
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    payload = json.loads(message.payload)
    logging.info("SUBSCRIBED Result: " + str(payload))

# Assign the callback function to the MQTT client, subscribing to the topic 'calculator' and starting the MQTT client loop
mqtt_client.loop_start()

mqtt_client.subscribe(SUBSCRIBER_TOPIC)
mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
```

Can someone help me understand if I have understood this requirement properly and the implementation is right?

Comment: MQTT is inherently asynchronous, where as HTTP is a synchronous protocol, trying to map a HTTP request to a MQTT publish and response requires a deep understanding of the difference. Why do you want to build a system like this, why can't the client just I talk MQTT directly to the backend?

Comment: What you have built may as well not use MQTT at all

Comment: My interpretation of the requirement is you should allow a client to be able to call the add via the rest api or an MQTT, so you should implement both. You should have your rest api which you have but it shouldnt do anything MQTT. And you should also have your code subscribe to an MQTT topic parse the payload and then return an MQTT response on the other topic

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle, if I understood correctly, I should only implement the server part of the MQTT? That means, as you mentioned, there should be a rest API (say `/`), that will subscribe to the `add` topic, get the values of `a` and `b`, and then do the additional and publish the result back to the `result` topic?

Comment: No the rest API and the MQTT are to act as 2 separate interfaces. So the client should be able to make an API call to add two number and get the result. Ot the client should be able to make an MQTT publish that your code should subscribe to parse the message, add the numbers then reply on the reply MQTT topic which the client would subscribe

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I didn't quite get you. I am new to MQTT and trying to understand this scenario. There are lots of answers to the same question I posted on other community pages but none of them is conveying the message to my understanding. Could you please break this down (high level) so I can understand it better?

Comment: @hardillb I didn't understand what you meant by `What you have built may as well not use MQTT at all`. Isn't my application logic is not right at all? Could you give me some understanding with pseudocode or anything that I can understand this logically as well?

Comment: In the code you have written the MQTT aspect is totally useless, it serves no meaningful purpose. @ChrisDoyle is correct, You either need to implement both the HTTP interface AND a MQTT interface that does the same thing (or if you want to be clever about it, pick on and use it to implement the other, in which case the MQTT interface should call the HTTP interface to do the actual addition, because as I said in my first comment, doing the other way round is **LOT** harder)

Comment: @hardillb can you point me to some examples on how to do this? This is still an ambiguity for a starter. An example would help me better understand what you are saying.

Comment: As this sound very like a homework assignment, have you discussed it with the person that set the assignment? But I will say consider this first. Assume there is no HTTP requirement, solve the problem JUST using MQTT